# Confused about global variable not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var clickCount = 1;
var slideCount = $('div.slide').length;

$('a#next-button').click(function() {
    if(clickCount < slideCount) {
        $('div.slide').animate({"left":"-=" + slideWidth}, 'slow');
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;
    }
});

$('p').text(clickCount);
```

It has a global variable called `clickCount`.

The `$('a#next-button').click(function() { …` updates the global variable with an increment of 1, each time the `<a>` element is clicked.

So, my question is, why does: `$('p').text(clickCount);`
not show me the updated clickCount on the page everytine the `<a>` tag is clicked. Instead it just shows 1 (the original assigned value).

Comment: First, you can use `clickCount++` if you want to increase by one, or `clickCount += 2` if by 2 and so on. Second, `slideWidth` is not defined (line 6).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ` SlideWidth ` is defined in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is being updated, but your function (`$('p').text(clickCount);`) is only being run once, and thus only using the value it sees.

To fix this, put the `$('p').text(clickCount);` within the `click` function.

```
$('a#next-button').click(function() {
  if(clickCount < slideCount) {
     $('div.slide').animate({"left":"-=" + slideWidth}, 'slow');
     clickCount = clickCount + 1;
     $('p').text(clickCount); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the text of the paragraph each time the variable changes. The paragraph doesn't magically track the value of the clickCount variable :

```
$('a#next-button').click(function() {
    if(clickCount < slideCount) {
        $('div.slide').animate({"left":"-=" + slideWidth}, 'slow');
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;
        $('p').text(clickCount); 
    }
});
```